Rollup config with rollup-plugin-less
I'm having trouble with the rollup-config
rollup: 3.29.4
rollup-plugin-less: 1.1.3
rollup.config.js:
export default [
  {
    input: 'index.js',
    plugins: [
      css(),
      **less(),**
      // Entry point for application build; can specify a glob to build multiple
      // HTML files for non-SPA app
      html({
        input: 'ml-src/index.html',
        output: 'build/index.html'
      }),
...

when I try and use it I continue to get the following error:
[!] RollupError: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
I tried updating rollup or trying other plugins but had trouble since I think the requirements were different rollup-styling
